# Getting 1 to N and N to 1

Tags: c#

I was trying to get a series of sum from 1 to N and N to 1.

The output should be like this :

```
12345 
54321 
12345 
54321 
12345
```

I dont know where's my mistake but my code's result is this :

```
12345
54321 
12345 
54321 
12345
54321 
12345 
54321 
12345
54321
```

This is my code :

```
        public static void Main (string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Masukkan Nilai : ");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) 
        {
          for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
          {
              Console.Write(j);
          }
          Console.WriteLine();
          for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
          {
              Console.Write(i);
          }
          Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

Comment: What you can do instead of writing two lines everytime, is check if `x` is odd or even, and write the corresponding line (odd: 12345, even: 54321)

Comment: The last `Console.WriteLine()` was supposed to create line break. If I remove that, the result is just the same, but without line break

Comment: Try and debug this with `n==1`. By the way, the outer for-loop is usually written as `for (int x=0; x<n; x++)` (start value 0, loop while `x<n`, instead of `x<=n`)

Comment: It's the whole `for(...){} + Console.WriteLine()` which is doubled in your main loop

Comment: @HansKeﬆing that'd be true for OP's main `for`, but I'd rather see a `for(int j=1...` than a `Console.Write(j+1);` (in the inner `for`s)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing the `x<=n` is to achieve the `n` downside.

Comment: @Rafalon Yes, that's true, for that particular case starting with 1 (or ending there, for descending) shows the intent better. That's why I said "usually" (and edited the comment - just in time)

Comment: @Syafiqur__ when you are just concerned about the number of iterations, you can start at 1 and continue up to (and including) n, or start at 0 and stop just before you reach n - same number of iterations

Comment: Yes I know that, But if I start from 0, the result will be 6, starts from 0, not 1 as what I wanted. Anyway, thank you for the help. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Syafiqur__ if you start at `0` and stop **before n** (note `<` instead of `<=`), you will loop the same number of times (5)

Comment: Noted. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do instead of writing two lines everytime, is check if `x` is odd or even, and write the corresponding line (odd: 12345, even: 54321):

```
for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) 
{
    // if x is odd, write 12345
    if(x%2 == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
        }
    }
    // if x is even, write 54321
    else
    {
        for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
        }
    }
    // in any case, go to a new line
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

---

Note that if you want to write your main loop `for(int x=0; x<n; x++)` instead of `for(int x=1; x<=n; x++)` you have to revert the odd/even logic.